# Android AsyncTask #2 Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having some problem with AsyncTask #2 fatal exception in Android. So what I am trying to do is single tap on map, get the coordinates X and Y and pass them to AsyncTask() class to execute a method to get the address. Here is the codes of my single tap and MyAsyncTask():

```
mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {
        public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
                eventModel.setEventX(String.valueOf(point.getX()));
                eventModel.setEventY(String.valueOf(point.getY()));
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(eventModel);
                CreateEvent.createEventDialog(context, point.getX(),
                        point.getY(), eventAddress);
                Log.i("Addr", eventAddress);
        }
    });
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}

public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Event, Integer, Double> {
    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(Event... params) {
        try {
            eventAddress = eventCtrl.getStreetAddressFromGeometry(eventModel.getEventX(), eventModel.getEventY());
            eventCtrl.retrieveEventJSON();
            if (params.length == 1) {
                eventCtrl.createEvent(params[0]);
                // Refresh map after successfully added event
                eventCtrl.retrieveEventJSON();
                eventCtrl.plotEventOnMap(context);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {   
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }
}
```

And the method in EventController to get the address based on XY:

```
public String getStreetAddressFromGeometry(String eventX, String eventY) {
    String streetName = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/revgeocode?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&location="+eventX+","+eventY+"");
        URLConnection conn = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String responseString;

        while ((responseString = br.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject rawObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray searchResults = rawObj.getJSONArray("GeocodeInfo");
                for (int i = 0; i < searchResults.length(); i++) {
                    streetName = searchResults.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "BLOCK")
                            + " " + searchResults.getJSONObject(i).getString("ROAD") + " SINGAPORE";
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return streetName;
}
```

After I get the address from single tap, I pass it to this method:

```
public static Event createEventDialog(final Context context,
        final double x, final double y, final String eventAddress) {
    AlertDialog.Builder AddDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    AddDialog.setTitle("Add Event");

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.create_event, null);
    txtEventName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtEventName);
    txtEventDesc = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtEventDesc);
    txtEventAddr = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtEventAddr);

    txtEventAddr.setText(eventAddress);

    AddDialog.setView(dialogView);
    AddDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    AddDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AddDialog.show();

    return addEventModel;
}
```

However, with these codes, I printed out the address from single tap, it's showing the address. But when I prompt out the dialog box, it supposed to display the address. However, it is not showing anything and after a few seconds, the application shut down with the error message:

```
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:663)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at Controller.EventController.plotEventOnMap(EventController.java:101)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.ENeighbourhoodActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(ENeighbourhoodActivity.java:213)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.ENeighbourhoodActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(ENeighbourhoodActivity.java:1)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-11 17:18:28.889: E/AndroidRuntime(4439):     ... 5 more
11-11 17:18:35.725: W/SurfaceView(4439): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439): Activity nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.ENeighbourhoodActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4169d570 that was originally added here
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.ENeighbourhoodActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4169d570 that was originally added here
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:428)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.CreateEvent.createEventDialog(CreateEvent.java:124)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.ENeighbourhoodActivity$3.onSingleTap(ENeighbourhoodActivity.java:192)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at com.esri.android.map.MapOnTouchListener.onSingleTap(Unknown Source)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at com.esri.android.map.MapGestureDetector$a.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:393)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
11-11 17:18:37.022: E/WindowManager(4439):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 17:18:38.209: I/Process(4439): Sending signal. PID: 4439 SIG: 9
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

```
AddDialog.setView(dialogView);
    AddDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    addEventModel = new Event();
                    addEventModel = onConfirmAddEventClicked(context, x, y);
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(addEventModel);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

So here is the part when user select Okay from dialogue box, it will get the user inputs, in this case it was done in onConfirmEventClicked. Then it will call the MyAsyncTask to execute DB insertion.

Comment: Could you please say which one is the row ENeighbourhoodActivity.java:213?

Comment: eventCtrl.plotEventOnMap(context);

Comment: **ResourcesNotFoundException** Check resources and IDs

Comment: The resourceNotFoundException is because in my AsyncTask, I passed in only one parameter. So no matter I click okay or cancel from the dialogue box, it just execute the DB insertion with empty field data. When I try to plot marker on map, it could not load the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `eventCtrl.plotEventOnMap(context);` on `postExecute` instead. This method appears to change the UI which can't be done on `doInBackground`

**Edit**

You will have to call `CreateEvent.createEventDialog` **only** after your AsyncTask finishes. For that I recomend creating an interface and pass it to your task. That will require some coding. Let's get started:

```
public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Event, Integer, Double> {
    public interface OnRoutineFinished{  //interface
        void onFinish();
    }
    private OnRoutineFinished mCallbacks;
    public MyAsyncTask(OnRoutineFinished callback){ //constructor with interface
        mCallbacks = callback;
    }

    public MyAsyncTask(){} //empty constructor to maintain compatibility

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(Event... params) {
        try {
            eventAddress = eventCtrl.getStreetAddressFromGeometry(eventModel.getEventX(), eventModel.getEventY());
            eventCtrl.retrieveEventJSON();
            if (params.length == 1) {
                eventCtrl.createEvent(params[0]);
                // Refresh map after successfully added event
                eventCtrl.retrieveEventJSON();
                eventCtrl.plotEventOnMap(context);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
        if(mCallbacks !=null)
            mCallbacks.onFinish(); //call interface on finish
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }
}
```

Next when you create your asyntask pass the event you want to call when the async finishes:

```
    new MyAsyncTask(new MyAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
             CreateEvent.createEventDialog(context, point.getX(),
                    point.getY(), eventAddress);  //this will be called after the task finishes
        }
    }).execute(eventModel);
```

Comment: But when the dialog box shows, the address is not showing. I tried to print it out inside the single tap method, it did returned something. DO you have any ideas why?

Comment: You're calling your Create dialog routine right after you start your async task. Keep in mind that the the code will keep going on after you call your async task, which means that `eventAddress` will not be populated. I suggest you change your `createEventDialog` call to `onPostExecute` too.

Comment: But with this, even I selected the cancel from dialogue box, it still execute the createEvent which is in the if statement if parameter passed in was one. Do you have any ideas to twist this around?

Comment: That's because it's your async that adds the event. You should only call `eventCtrl.createEvent` if the user clicked yes and not on your asynctask.

Comment: eventCtrl.createEvent needs to be in myAynstask because it's accessing the method in my servlet

Comment: Yes but `eventCtrl.createEvent(params[0])` can only be called if the user chooses `OK` from your Dialog. You can create a new async task that calls `createEvent` and call it after the user clicks ok

Comment: @PetroOliveria Okay let me try to do it first. :) So basically I need to create another interface in MyAsyncTask like what you did for OnRoutineFinised?

Comment: No. You just need to create a new asyn task where you're going to call `eventCtrl.createEvent(params[0]);` and remove it from the initial one. So basicly what you're doing is: first fetch the data from the servlet (address AFAIK), next show the dialog, if the user clicks yes start another task to create the event.

Comment: I've edited the question already. Could you please help me take a look? I am abit confused

Comment: The question is now too broad since there are multiple things that are wrong :\ I don't think you know how async task works. Also why are you calling `onConfirmAddEventClicked`?

Comment: onConfirmAddEventClicked was called when user select okay from dialogue box. it's basically getting all user inputs and return as an event object

Comment: This is not a really vague question. You're calling the same async twice, you're still not implementing the onFinish listener, you don't seem to know what runs on main thread and what not, you don't seem to understand how to pass arguments on an async task. The pseudo code, and I already said that, is: Call asyntask1 to get ONLY the address, return the address to onPostExecute, show a dialog with that address, user clicks yes, open asyntask2 that ONLY creates event.